# how to display an empty string when a number is equal to 0 in angular expression

Tags: angularjs, syntax

```
<div>{{a.value | number:0}}</div>
```

this is what I have. I would like to display just "" if the value is 0. Anyway I can do that within the same line? or I have to filter it out in a controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty ugly but you can do it like this:

```
<div>{{a.value ? (a.value | number:0) : '' }}</div>
```

Not sure if there is more clearer way though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-bind` and `ng-if`. Like this:

```
<span ng-bind="a.value" ng-if="a.value"></span>
```

Comment: Then it will be `<div ng-bind="a.value | number:0" ng-if="a.value"></div>`. This is good!